# How to configure message on Remote Desktop access on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: remote-desktop, login, windows-server-2008-r2, prompt

I have Windows Server 2008 R2. When a user is logged in and another user (with same credentials) tries to logon, I need to display a prompt with the message that another user is already logged in.

If it is possible, the message should be customizable. How can I do this?

Comment: Doesn't Windows do this automatically? You cannot customize it as far as I'm aware, but it is there.

Comment: No, in this case, one person logged in with admin is kicked off for another person who try to login with the same user, with no message or warning.

Comment: If this gets moved to SF it will be a dupe of this: http://serverfault.com/questions/383237/server-08-rdp-possible-to-warn-if-same-user-is-already-connected Which actually has a kind of slick answer...

Answer (score -1):

Usually it allows minimum of some users to login to server, once the threshold limit reaches and if someone tried login to server, it displays the prompt with appropriate message stating maximum users have logged on..

Comment: In my case i have only one user account.
One person is loggedin with admin user.
And when another person try to login, it just do, and kick the first person.

Thanks

Comment: This is entirely unrelated to the question.